# Converting a char function to deal with strings C++

Tags: c++, string, rsa

I have been slightly over-ambitious with my first project and need a little bit of help if that's ok? I need to convert the returnChar function to be able to return a string of values; at the moment it works on individual characters. It is the deciphering process of an RSA encryption and works perfectly when enciphering and deciphering one letter at a time, this is very frustrating as I just can't do it, I have managed for the encryption portion! Thanks for any help in advance, sorry about the trivial question.

**Only the returnChar function is the problem, but I'm including all of my code in case anyone is curious**

(P.S p and q are tiny just to make testing easy I know that it's not secure at this size)

EDIT: This is my first post so I'm not sure if I've broken some kind of rule? This post has been voted down, could anyone let me know why so that I don't do it again in future?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long int modinv(unsigned long long int u, unsigned long long int v)
{
    unsigned long long int inv, u1, u3, v1, v3, t1, t3, q;
    unsigned long long int iter;

    u1 = 1;
    u3 = u;
    v1 = 0;
    v3 = v;

    iter = 1;

    while (v3 != 0)
    {
        q = u3 / v3;
        t3 = u3 % v3;
        t1 = u1 + q * v1;

        u1 = v1;
        v1 = t1;
        u3 = v3;
        v3 = t3;
        iter = -iter;
    }

    if (u3 != 1)
        return 0;
    if (iter < 0)
        inv = v - u1;
    else
        inv = u1;
    return inv;
}

int modExp(int b, int e, int m)
{
    int remainder;
    int x = 1;

    while (e != 0)
    {
        remainder = e % 2;
        e = e / 2;

        if (remainder == 1)
            x = (x * b) % m;
        b = (b * b) % m; // New base equal b^2 % m
    }
    return x;
}

char returnChar(unsigned long long int x)
{
    return (char) x + 87;
}

int main()
{
    long unsigned int p = 17;
    unsigned long long int q = 23;
    unsigned long long int phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    unsigned long long int e = 7;
    unsigned long long int c = 327;
    unsigned long long int n = p * q;
    unsigned long long int d = modinv(e, phi);

    {
        cout << returnChar(modExp(c, d, n));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write `unsigned long long int` - it just makes code artificially `long`er. Use `unsigned long long` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what difference will this make to how my code runs? I'm just not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelRad What is a _'char function'_ and what you're consdering to be a _string_? Elaborate please ...

Comment: I am able to have an output of "a", "b", "m" etc when that is what was encrypted (using a different program). But I am unable to have an output of "ab", "mhn", "words" etc Does that make sense?

Comment: What are the results from using a debugger?  Have you printed out variables?

Comment: Which RSA algorithm are you implementing?

Comment: I'm implementing the RSA algorithm described in Appendix J of "The Code Book" by Dr Simon Singh. It's basically one pass of M = C ^ d (mod N). The rest is just calculating d and defining 'modExp' which is just modular exponentiation with in-built simplification to allow large numbers to be used.

Comment: @MichaelRad - My advice to you is to first write the function that simulates in some way the "stringing" of those characters.  For example, a loop that outputs those characters one at a time.  Once you have that, then we can suggest how to store that output.  Right now, all I see is one function that outputs a single char -- I see no loop to emulate or suggest you are able to create a string.